# How to call methods from other classes inside a class in javascript es6?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I have trouble calling a method from one class in other classes. The only way I made it work was to pass in the class (that has the method) and then use new keyword. I dont think it can be right/good to always using new keyword in every class I want to use the method (when having multiple classes containing mult. methods). How can I do that? Also, inheriting from other classes isnt a good way eeither as I would inherit all of its properties and it wouldnt really fit as i dont have parent/child relationships. Could anyone help? Thanks!

html:

```
<input id="title"/>
<input id="description"/>
<button id="add">Add</button>


class EventHandler{
    constructor(Todo){}
    init() {
        const button = document.querySelector("#add");
        const todo = new Todo();
        button.onclick = todo.addItem;
    }
}

class Todo {
    constructor(title, description, UIManager){
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
    addItem() {
        const uiManager = new UIManager;
        const todoItem = uiManager.getData();
    }
}

class TodoManager {
    constructor(){}
}

class UIManager {
    constructor(){}

    getData() {
        const title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
        const description = document.querySelector("#description").value;
        const todoItem = new Todo(title, description);
        return todoItem;
    }
}


(() => {
const todoManager = new TodoManager();
const uiManager = new UIManager();
const eventHandler = new EventHandler();
let todoItem = uiManager.getData();
eventHandler.init()
})()
```

ps.: I was thinking somehow to do it insight my init function, but there I havent created my todoitem yet and I keep getting errors about undefined classes whatever I tried here.

Answer (score 1):

Why is UIManager a class? It doesn't create anything useful. If you want a function library, just use a plain object:

```
const UIManager = {
  getData: () => {
    const title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
    const description = document.querySelector("#description").value;
    const todoItem = new Todo(title, description);
    return todoItem;
  }
}
```

Same thing with EventHandler.

If said classes *did* return a useful object you wanted to work with, but you still wanted to access general class utility methods not related to those objects, you could use the `static` keyword:

```js
class Something {
  constructor() {
    this.something = 'somethingelse';
  }
  static getInfo() {
    return 'some info';
  }
}
console.log(Something.getInfo());
```

Comment: there will be of course much more code, with my seperation of different class (uiManager etc) I wanted to follow the MVC pattern. Making a class an object doesnt really make sense- I am trying to figure out how to call methods from other classes which might not be necessary with those few lines of code but will be necessary.

Comment: Also, so the only way is to use static keyword?

Comment: Javascript isn't Java - don't feel like you have to wrap everything in a class just for organizational purposes. Objects work just fine as function containers. Use a class when you *want* to instantiate a meaningful object, but otherwise, use some other method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some reason to make `UIManager` a class, make the method `static`:

```
class UIManager {
    constructor(){}

    static getData() {
        const title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
        const description = document.querySelector("#description").value;
        const todoItem = new Todo(title, description);
        return todoItem;
    }
}

let todoItem = UIManager.getData();
```